# Adding Google Maps layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

Please tell me why we use:

```
max Extent: new Open Layers.Bounds(
        -20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)
```

when adding Google Maps layer in OpenLayers? i.e. please tell me about this function?
    )

Answer (score 1):

You can set a maxExtent that differs from the default maxExtent 
in order to be able to zoom to this maxExtent with the OpenLayers.Control.ZoomToMaxExtent.

Your maxExtent is nearly the whole world-Extent (-180, -85.05112877980659, 180, 85.0511287798066) but could be set to a smaller area.

See this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/cpthr93m/